# Как пишется словосочетание "ценностно()ориентационный"?

Tags: грамматика, орфоэпия

"Ценностно-ориентационный" — есть ли такое слово и как оно пишется?

Answer (score 2):

Раздельно. Потому, что это два слова. 
А если серьёзно, что оно значит? Может, все-таки "ценностно ориентированный"?
Так, как вы написали, получается, что это тот, который связан с ценностями и ориентацией. Что-то малореальное.
Если же имелся в виду тот, который, скажем, помогает ориентироваться в ценностях, то раздельно. Но вообще-то лучше слова не изобретать.

Answer (score 2):

Есть понятие ценностно-ориентированный, недавно было "ценностно-ориентирующий".Правописание не устоялось. Если это просто определение, то раздельно:  У меня к этому был ценностно ориентированный подход.Подход какой? -ориентированный. В каком отношении? как?-ценностно.
По правилам русского языка раздельно, ценностно - наречие, отдельное слово.

Если же Вы имеете в виду термин педагогики "ценностно-ориентированный подход", то через дефис, так написано во всех важных педагогических работах. Объяснить не могу.Возможно, потому что есть ценностный подход. Иногда термины пишутся не по правилам. Например, всемирно известный - раздельно, а всемирно - исторический - через дефис, хотя логично было бы писать слитно, ведь образовано от подчинительного словосочетания: всемирная история.Поэтому определитесь: это термин?-через дефис, общеупотребительное определение - раздельно.